# Understanding char * to int * conversion and its meaning

Tags: c++, c, casting

I have the following simple piece of code,

```
unsigned long the_function(const char* p){
        int* ip = (int*)p;
        printf("%d\n",ip);
}
```

I know that the first line cast is meaning less but that the code given to me.

Now when i just pass "a" to the function i get the constant output

```
4196024
```

could someone explain to me what is the meaning.

Comment: You are printing the address of p which is a pointer

Comment: It makes no sense at all in this code; you could just as well do `printf("%d\n", (int)p);`.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `printf` at all?

Comment: FWIW, this is undefined behaviour because you're passing a pointer for a %d argument.

Comment: Also it may be an alignment violation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's printing the address of the string.

Comment: It's trying to at any rate. Pointer may not be the same size as `int`.

Comment: The correct way to print an arbitrary pointer is to use `%p` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to print the address of the `pi` pointer which is of type `(int *)`. The address is represented with 8 bytes, but ints may be represented with 4 bytes, so when you attempt to print `pi` using `%d` only a portion of the pointer is printed. As [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) pointed out using `%p` is the correct way to print a pointer address.

As an aside, you're converting the `char *` pointer to a type of `int *` but you never try to access the value of what `int *` is pointing at, in case that's what you were trying to do.

Comment: The size is not the only potential problem; e.g. the calling convention might pass integers and pointers differently